AEM/Sling how to get a Map of CAConfig values
In Adobe AEM we have a deeply nested structure with multiple context aware configs and for editors it is often not clear which config is currently active. What makes it more complex: it might happen that a content copy deletes a CaConfig on the author although it is still present on the publish environment (please don't ask).
That's why I would like to create a resourcetype bound servlet that prints all CaConfig values for a particular page, in this style:



Key
Value
Config Path




MyKey1
SomeValue1
/conf/site1/...


MyKey2
SomeValue2
/conf/site1/...



so that the editor can see at one glance which props have been configured without opening each every config in the hierarchy.
What is the best approach? Maybe ACS has a solution for this already?
What I did: Straightforward approach, created a servlet and used the ConfigurationBuilder to adapt the page. You would get the effective key/values for each CaConfig but not the path to the config where this value is configured. Feels a little cumbersome.

I have tried the Context-Aware Configuration Editor (CA Config Editor) provided by WCM.io. This editor offers a Visual Editor interface for managing context-aware configurations. wcm.io

Thanks for your answer but I don´t want to edit/manage them, I want to see the hierarchy. And the editor won´t work on the publish instance.
